# How do I escape a dot character for an rsync command?

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

I'm trying to do...

```
ssh -av -e deploy@domain.com:/var/www/domain.com /Users/user/workspace/domain
```

But it's outputting this (I presume because of the period character):

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
Bad escape character 'deploy@domain.com:/var/www/domain.com'.
```

I have tried

```
ssh -av -e deploy@domain.com:/var/www/domain\.com /Users/user/workspace/domain
```

And various combinations with quotes. What is the right syntax?

Comment: What?  Take a look at your command again.  It says `ssh ... -e`.  Where is the `rsync`?

Comment: Well, that was awkward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
ssh -av -e deploy@domain.com:/var/www/domain.com /Users/user/workspace/domain
```

You're not executing `rsync` at all and `ssh` is telling you that `deploy@domain.com:/var/www/domain.com` is not a valid escape character.

Read `ssh(1)`:

> -e escape_char
>               Sets the escape character for sessions with a pty (default: `~'). The escape character is only recognized at the beginning of a line.  The escape character followed by a dot (`.') closes the connection; followed by control-Z suspends the connection; and followed by itself sends the escape character once.  Setting the character to ``none'' disables any escapes and makes the session fully transparent.

I think what you meant to run is this:

```
rsync -e ssh -av deploy@domain.com:/var/www/domain.com /Users/user/workspace/domain
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Yes, this was the problem.